# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer esta jerarquía de controles (Panel, TreeView)?, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2010

Tenía la siguiente jerarquía:

[image: Estructura anterior]

La cual recorro de la siguiente forma:

```
Panel[] paneles_principales;
Label[] items;
FlowLayoutPanel[] flowLayout;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    recorrer_opciones<Panel>(panel_principal.Controls.OfType<Panel>(), true);
}

private void recorrer_opciones<T>(IEnumerable<Control> controles, bool recursiva) where T : Control
{
     int cantidad_hijos = 0; //Para identificar si el elemento actual tiene hijos.
     if (recursiva)
     {
         paneles_principales = controles.OfType<Panel>().ToArray();

         for (int indice = 0; indice < paneles_principales.Length; indice++)
         {
             flowLayout = paneles_principales[indice].Controls.OfType<FlowLayoutPanel>().ToArray();
             cantidad_hijos = flowLayout[0].Controls.OfType<Label>().Count();

             if (cantidad_hijos > 0)
                 recorrer_opciones<Label>(flowLayout[0].Controls.OfType<Label>(), false);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         items = controles.OfType<Label>().ToArray();

         for (int indice = 0; indice < items.Length; indice++)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Items\n\n" + "Name: " + items[indice].Name +
                             "\nText: " + items[indice].Text);
         }
     }
 }
```

Esto me funciona perfectamente, recorre todos los elementos, pero he decidido cambiar está jerarquía actual por está:

[image: jerarquía Actual]

En la cual he sustituido los `flowLayoutPanel` y `Label` por un control `TreeView`, ahora necesito recorrer los nodos de estos `TreeView` y recorrer todos los nodos hijos que estos contengan. Modifiqué mi función para lograr esto pero no logro recorrer todos los hijos que contienen los nodos.

```
Panel[] paneles_principales;
TreeView[] nodos;
TreeNodeCollection coleccion_nodos;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    recorrer_opciones<Panel>(panel_principal2.Controls.OfType<Panel>(), true);
}

private void recorrer_opciones<T>(IEnumerable<Control> controles, bool recursiva) where T : Control
{
     int cantidad_hijos = 0; //Para identificar si el elemento actual tiene hijos.
     if (recursiva)
     {
         paneles_principales = controles.OfType<Panel>().ToArray();

         for (int indice = 0; indice < paneles_principales.Length; indice++)
         {
             nodos = paneles_principales[indice].Controls.OfType<TreeView>().ToArray(); 
             cantidad_hijos = nodos[0].Nodes.Count;

             if (cantidad_hijos > 0)
                 recorrer_opciones<TreeView>(nodos.AsEnumerable<TreeView>(), false);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         TreeView t = (TreeView)controles.OfType<TreeView>().FirstOrDefault();
         coleccion_nodos = t.Nodes;

         foreach (TreeNode item in coleccion_nodos)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Primer foreach\n" + Name: " + item.Name +
                             "\nText: " + item.Text);

             foreach (TreeNode item2 in item.Nodes)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Segundo foreach\n" + "Name: " + item2.Name + 
                                 "\nText: " + item2.Text);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

> De esta forma solo recorre los nodos principales, Nodo0, nodo1, nodo2 etc.. y los nodos: 3,4,15 que son hijos no los recorre.

**¿Cómo puedo recorrer todos los nodos?**, que haga tal como hace con la otra jerarquía que se llame recursivamente sin importar cuantos hijos o sub-hijos  tenga un nodo. Sin alterar la llamada de mi función:

```
 private void recorrer_opciones<T>(IEnumerable<Control> controles, bool recursiva) where T : Control
```

Comment: @gbianchi los recorro porque esos nodos serán opciones que cargaré de la base de datos, y las habilitaré o no dependiendo de si el usuario tiene permiso a ver alguna opción de esas, aqui solo mostré un ejemplo básico, pero no logro hacerlo.

Comment: @gbianchi y como puedo hacer eso, me presentas un ejemplo?  Que no altere mucho mi función actual

Comment: @gbianchi es que no puedo agrupar todo en un solo arbol, porque son opciones distintas, por ejemplo: en el Treeview1 iran los mantenimientos, treeview2 los procesos, treeview3 reportes.. y asi, por eso no puedo agrupar todo en un solo árbol, aunque aunque "Mantenimiento", "Procesos", "Reportes" pueden ser nodos padres dentro de un mismo arbol, los quiero en arboles distintos.

Comment: Tenes una diccionario con clave(el arbol) que adentro tiene un diccionario con clave (item del menu) y adentro el nodo del menu. Y todo se te simplifica. Con linq ubicas los nodos que queres desabilitar y listo.

Comment: @gbianchi muéstrame un ejemplo por favor

Comment: En un rato te escribo una respuesta

Comment: Como armas tu arbol. ya sabes de antees como se arma? o viene de una db los nodos?

Comment: @gbianchi las opciones vienen desde la Bd, pero en tiempo diseño están todas las opciones agregadas y al momento de cargar de la bd simplemente quitara los nodos a los que el usuario no tenga permiso

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion simple a tu problema, es recorrer directamente los arboles. Ya que sabes cuales son, recorrer todo el arbol de controles buscando donde estan no tiene mucho sentido.

El siguiente codigo, agrega los nodos de los arboles (que ya sabes cuales son) a un diccionario, del cual luego podrias buscar los items que necesites mas facilmente.

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, TreeNode>> Menu = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, TreeNode>>();
.....
ObtenerNodos(treeView1,"Menu1");
.....
private void ObtenerNodos(TreeView T, string nombre)
{
    Dictionary<string, TreeNode> MenuLocal = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();
    Menu.Add(nombre, MenuLocal);
    foreach (TreeNode tn in T.Nodes)
    {
        RecorrerNodos(tn, MenuLocal);
        MenuLocal.Add(tn.Name, tn);
    }
}

private void RecorrerNodos(TreeNode tn, Dictionary<string,TreeNode> MenuLocal)
{
    if (tn.Nodes.Count == 0)
        return;
    foreach (TreeNode nodes in tn.Nodes)
    {
        RecorrerNodos(nodes, MenuLocal);
        MenuLocal.Add(nodes.Name, nodes);
    }
}
```

Si queres trabajar los nodos desde el diccionario, sabiendo a que item del menupertenecen y cual es el nombre del nodo, podes obtenerlos del diccionario.

Pro ejemplo, si quisieras obtener del Menu1 el item Node0 harias algo asi:

```
var v = this.Menu["Menu1"];
((TreeNode) v["node0"]) <--- esto es un TreeNode
```

Ahora si todavia queres trabajar buscando el elemento cada vez, solo tenes que cambiar la funcion recorrer nodos, para que una vez que encuentre el nodo, lo guarde en una variable del form y listo.

Comment: Se me hará complicado aplicarlo de esta manera, debido a la estructura actual que ya llevo programada en todo el sistema, pero veré que hago entonces.

Comment: Una idea, obten la coleccion desde tu base de datos q constituye nodos de nivel 0 (mantenimientos, procesos, reportes, etc) y por cada uno de ellos obten la lista de elementos a los q tiene acceso el usuario. Recorre los nodos de nivel cero pintandolos y a su vez los nodos hijos. Es otro enfoque, lo veo mas practico. Recuerda q en tu base de datos tienes registros o tuplas y en tu aplicacion una estructura de árbol, orientada a objeto. Quizás los nodos de nivel 0 tuyos esten predefinidos, no tan dinamicos, esa parte no la se.